# How to make a new playlist in VLC player and assign songs?

Tags: vlc

How can I make a new playlist in VLC player (2.1.6 Rincewind), give it a name and assign songs to it? There is no menu called 'playlist' and menu item 'new playlist'.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC under "View", there you have an entry "Playlist".
When you have organized you playlist you can save and name it with the following step: Under "Media" you have the entry "Save Playlist to File".

Comment: okay, now how to load the plalist?

Answer (score 0):

Select Playlist from the View menu, then you can add items as desired.

Comment: Okay, Now how to load the playlist?

Comment: Media/Open File

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This will open the playlist then right click Add File or you can Add all files from a specific directory using Add directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VLC generates playlists with the `.xspf` file extension. To add this, just select **Media Library** and then **right click** in the right side area then select your playlist files. There's no need to do this every time, only once.

[image]